# Using mutiple datasources in myBatis and Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, mybatis

I have an application that uses Spring+MyBatis and I have a  Mapper interface to hold the SQL queries.

**Mapper.java**

```
package it.helloworld.mybatis;

import it.helloworld.dao.model.Numbers;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;

public interface Mapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM numbers")
    List<Numbers> getNumbers();


}
```

I have used the **MapperScannerConfigurer** to use this Mapper as follows:

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="it.helloworld.ibatis" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory1" />
    </bean>
```

I have used the name 'sqlSessionFactory1' because I have mutiple datasources in my application.

My question is:

I would like to change the interface to an XML file. Meaning I want to store my SQL query in an XML instead of an Interface. Can I configure MapperScannerConfigurer to do read SQL from an XML instead of an interface.? If yes, how.? If not, what should I use so as to make minimum code changes.?

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://mybatis.github.io/spring/factorybean.html for more details on configuring your sqlSessionFactory1

Answer (score 0):

The world has move on from MapperScannerConfigurer, then too let me answer this one. All you need in @MapperScan annotation.